# error TS2322: Type "below" is not assignable to type 'LegendPosition'

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

I use ngx-charts API, in order to show data with a pie chart on my web app.
When I tried modifying the chart's legend position, it showed the following error message:

> "error TS2322: Type '"below"' is not assignable to type
> 'LegendPosition'.".

I am using Angular 12, and ngx-charts API to use its nice charts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dug couple of hours until I found a solution.
The problem was with the string itself. when I wrote on my html file "[legendPosition]="'below'", it just did not recognize it, i.e. the request's content.

on html page (on ngx-charts tag):

```
[legendPosition]="legendPosition"
```

in its corresponding ts file, inside the exported class:

```
public legendPosition: LegendPosition = LegendPosition.Below;
```

and of course, this won't work unless you import LegendPosition:

```
import { LegendPosition } from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
```

Now, instead of receiving a string, [lgegentPosition] will use a LegendPosition object.
By the way, you can see that I have used "LegendPosition.**Below**". This is not the only way to present the legend, but just an example.

Comment: u can also write [legendPosition]="'below'" in html and it will works fine ('below' as string) OR legendPosition="below" like this

Comment: It did not work for me. When I tried to do this, the error message I described above appeared.